# How to recover FTP password from dreamweaver mx 2004?

Tags: ftp, passwords, dreamweaver

Let's say you have dreamweaver mx 2004 installed and it is the only remaining source of your FTP password. How do you extract this FTP password?

It is possible to see how many characters the FTP password is through the settings. I exported the settings into a file which gave me a field called "pw" which was a bunch of numbers. When I put it into online tools, it reveals what looks like some of the password, but fails, but the rest is garbled. What do I do?

Comment: Have you considered downloading Belarc Advisor? http://download.cnet.com/Belarc-Advisor/3000-2094_4-10007277.html

Comment: Why don't you just simply change the password to the FTP account?

Comment: @A Hawkins could you explain why should one consider downloading Belarc advisor ?

Comment: I have not used Belarc advisor that much, mainly for serial numbers for programs, perhaps with the FTP software being used, the password may well be the "serial number"
If not it does give you some nifty alerts about your PC anyway like missing security updates for example.

Comment: @Ramhound That's what I was thinking (higher ups don't want to change it because it could break other things (I'm new)).

Comment: A human most know the password then.

Comment: @Ramhound At one point yes. (I think whoever set all this up is gone now. They've accessed it exclusively through dreamweaver ever since.)

Comment: @Ramhound (Yes, I know this situation is problematic all around.)